# JSFiddle make an XMLHTTPRequest to a plain text/srt file

Tags: javascript, github, mootools, jsfiddle, gist

I can use JSFiddle's `/echo/` api without any problem, but it refuses to work with just plain text responses.

```
var request = new Request({
    url: '/echo/text/',
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    onSuccess: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    data: 'Hello, World!'
});

request.send();
```

However, after looking through the documentation a bit more, it seemed to only support `/echo/html/`, `/echo/json/` and `/echo/jsonp/`. So I decided to try using gist:

```
var request = new Request({
    url: '/gh/get/response.srt/3beed381fafac128be86/',
    method: 'GET',
    async: true,
    onSuccess: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});

request.send();
```

None of these will work. Surely there is a way to receive a **plain text** response?

**P.S.** The response I would like to receive can be found here: https://gist.github.com/nbish11/3beed381fafac128be86/

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `/echo/html`?

Comment: It only returns an empty string.

Comment: Are you sending the data correctly? `{html: 'your text here'}` (as explained in the documentation)

Comment: Success! The mistake I made was using the MooTools `Request.HTML` class, which automatically parses the string into html nodes.